# No viable overloaded '=' in C++ vector

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11, vector

I am trying to change my bool vector, items[0] to true in game.cpp/.hpp via DeerPark.cpp. However, I cannot figure out why Xcode is throwing this error message. Thank you all for your time and assistance.

This is my error message,

```
No viable overloaded '='
```

and it take place in DeerPark.cpp when I do

```
input[1]= true; //and
input[0]= true;
```

Game.hpp

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Game
{
    private:
        std::vector<bool> items = std::vector<bool>(3);
    public:
        int intRange(int min, int max, int input);
        void printMenu();
};
```

Game.cpp

```
#include "Game.hpp"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void Game::printMenu()
{
    items[0] = false;
    items[1] = false;
    items[2] = false;
}
```

DeerPark.hpp

```
#include <vector>
#include "Game.hpp"
class DeerPark : public Space
{
    protected:
        int feedCounter;
    public:
        DeerPark();

    void feed(Character *person, std::vector<bool>*input);
    void get(Character *person, std::vector<bool>*input);
    void kick(Character *person);
};
```

DeerPark.cpp

```
#include "DeerPark.hpp"
#include "Space.hpp"
#include <vector>
#include "Game.hpp"

using namespace std;

DeerPark::DeerPark() : Space()
{
    feedCounter = 0;
}
void DeerPark::feed(Character *person, vector<bool>*input)
{

    feedCounter = feedCounter + 1;

    if(feedCounter == 3)
    {
       input[1]= true;
    }
}
void DeerPark::get(Character *person, vector<bool>*input)
{
        Input[0] = true;
}
void DeerPark::kick(Character *person)
{
    person->setStrength(-5);
}
```

Comment: Surely there was a specific line indicated by that error message.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: If that was actually the problem, then it is a bug in the implementation. `std::vector<bool>::reference` is supposed to have `operator=(bool)` implemented. I doubt any implementations in use have such an ommision.

Comment: Tow issues: 1.- In function `get` you are using a pointer to a vector ( `vector<bool>*input>`) and you are using the  `Input`, whit capital "I".. 2.- i suppost that `vector<bool>*input>` is used as `Input[x]`, but it must you are handle de it as a pointer of an array of many objects of `vector<bool>*input` intraducible of a vector of `bool`. Change the definición of your metido to `vector<bool>&input` to pass a reference of the vector and use it as you want.

Comment: @JorgeOmarMedra: The answer section is below.

Comment: @JorgeOmarMedra Thanks for the explanation! That was indeed the problem. (*input)[0] works as well!

Comment: I agree wit you, @JustinS, and, As Carl answered, it s because it used the dereference operator that allow access to the  pointed value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in `DeerPark::feed`, the `input` argument is a `vector<bool>*` pointer, and therefore `input[1]` would be a reference to a `vector<bool>`, and `vector<bool>::operator=` doesn't accept a `bool` value. That's why the compiler complains about "No viable overloaded '='".

The correct way to fix this is to dereference the pointer:

```
(*input)[1]=true;
```

Same issue with `DeerPark::get` (after fixing the typo where `Input` should be `input`).

Answer (score 3):

It appears you are writing `Input[0]` with a capital `I` while the parameter is in fact called `input`. You are attempting to assign to something that does not exist.

Specifically here:

```
void DeerPark::get(Character *person, vector<bool>*input)
{
        Input[0] = true;
}
```

Change that to `(*input)[0] = true;`

Also, like others are pointing out, since it's passed as a pointer you must dereference the vector before you can subscript it. Also shown in the above snippet. Otherwise you are trying to assign to the pointer. So in short, a typo and an indirection error.

Answer (score 0):

`vector<bool>*input` function parameter is a pointer to `vector` so to access first element you will need to write `(*input)[0]`. Or (even better) pass by reference:

```
void DeerPark::feed(Character *person, vector<bool> & input)
```